# Apparent "Bug" with Pickup and Dropoff Blocks

Tags: simulation, anylogic

It appears that when an agent is picked up by the "container" at point A and delivered to Point B, internally it remains at Point A. I have fought with trying to Dropoff agents at Point B in several models and then move it from Point B, only to realize that when it moves it moves from Point A. I took Felipe's model "Transporting Boxes - Batch and Pickup" and just put a simple move to action after the dropoff, and the agent was moved from the original location A. This behavior cannot be right. What purpose is the dropoff block if the agent stays at the original location? You can see the modified model here [See Modified Transporting Boxes to show agent location](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o3v35kxbzhdlts/learningBatchAndPickupMod.zip?dl=0)

Is there a way for the model to actually move with the container and be dropped off and show up at that location? Or would i have to just do a dedicated moveTo block for just the agent? Also even if you specify "Agent Location" in all the queue and delay blocks as the destination, it doesnt appear to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, the problem is that the default value for the properties for each block is "restore agent location on exit" as you can see in the figure:
[image: restore agent location]

In the queue after the dropoff if you have that checked, the agent will return to the previous location, which is the node before getting picked up...

Just uncheck that box, and everything will work as you planned... I think you can do that either in the queue block or the moveTo block, it won't make any difference

Comment: Thanks Felipe for the prompt response. I have always wondered what exactly this "restore agent does", this is almost like the default setting of "1" for the capacity of the Delay block that always gets you a crash.

Comment: `this is almost like the default setting of "1" for the capacity of the Delay block that always gets you a crash`

Actually that is 'correct' as well. You get the crash if you don't have a Queue before the Delay: the Delay does not have any inherent 'storage' for waiting agents (unlike a Service block which is a Queue-Seize-Delay-Release), and that is a deliberate conceptual choice in terms of what the block does.